# Bubble Maps Geospatial Data

Tags: python, import, spreadsheet

I am super new to python. I have this excel file, I want to import it and create bubble map for CGR values and x-y being the spatial co-ordinates. Please also include what I have to import as well.
[Excel file for bubble maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CwtF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pandas, matplotlib, seaborn and should insert the path of the excel file in the file as the value of the variable name_file_excel. Then you can run the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

name_file_excel = 'name.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(name_file_excel, index_col=0,
              dtype={'x': int, 'y': int, 'CGR': float})

sns.scatterplot(data=data, x="x", y="y", size="CGR", legend=False, sizes=(20, 2000))

# show the graph
plt.show()
```